# MySQL GROUP BY to find duplicates with where clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, duplicates

Right now I have:

```
custom_id| field_id | value
-------------------------
 20987   | 72       | No mark
 20987   | 122      | None
 20987   | 126      | http
 20999   | 72       | No mark
 20999   | 122      | 100
 20999   | 126      | http
```

I need to find custom_id which matches three clauses. First - field_id = 72 and value = 'No mark'. Second - field_id = 122 and value = ' '.Third - field_id = 126 and value like '%http%'.

I run this query:

```
SELECT custom_id, value, field_id, count(custom_id) 
WHERE(field_id = '72' AND value = 'No mark') 
OR (field_id = '126' AND value like '%http%') 
OR (field_id = '122' AND value ='') 
GROUP BY custom_id
HAVING count(custom_id)=3 
LIMIT 10000
```

And I had the result:

```
[(20987,72,'No mark',3)]
```

How can I order by or sort values in 'group by / count' clause to have the result like:

```
[(20987,126,'http',3)]
```

Comment: What is the logic behind why you expect to see that particular row from the three or more matches per `custom_id`?  Please add the exact expected output based on the sample input you did show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you could use window functions to solve this. First, filter on the records that match the 3 conditions, while performing a window count and assigning a conditional rank that puts the `'http'` value first. Then, the outer query filters on the records that have a window count of 3 and that ranked first:

```
SELECT custom_id, value, field_id, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY custom_id ORDER BY value LIKE '%http%') rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY custom_id) cnt
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE 
           (field_id = '72' AND value = 'No mark') 
        OR (field_id = '126' AND value like '%http%') 
        OR (field_id = '122' AND value ='') 
) x
WHERE cnt = 3 AND rn = 1
LIMIT 10000
```

Side note: based on your sample data, `value LIKE '%http%'` would be better written `value = 'http'`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jT3bSWnRmpQSsvPABAgy2/2)**:

```
| custom_id | value | field_id | cnt |
| --------- | ----- | -------- | --- |
| 20987     | http  | 126      | 3   |
```

---

In earlier versions, where window functions are not available, you can perform aggregation in a subquery to generate a list of `custom_id`s that satisfy the conditions, and then `JOIN` the results with the original table, while filtering on the record that has the `value` that you expect:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT custom_id
    FROM mytable
    WHERE
            (field_id = '72' AND value = 'No mark') 
        OR (field_id = '126' AND value like '%http%') 
        OR (field_id = '122' AND value ='') 
    GROUP BY custom_id
    HAVING count(custom_id)=3 
) x ON x.custom_id = t.custom_id
WHERE t.value like '%http%'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jT3bSWnRmpQSsvPABAgy2/3)** (same results as above).

Answer (score 0):

if you want retrive the custom_id that match the condition
You could use some self  join on table

```
SELECT a.custom_id
FROM my_table a
INNER JOIN my_tbale b  ON a.custom_id = b.custom_id 
  AND a.field_id = '72' 
    AND a.value = 'No mark'
INNER JOIN JOIN my_tbale c  ON a.custom_id = c.custom_id 
  AND b.field_id = '126' 
    AND b.value like '%http%'
WHERE a.field_id = '122' 
  AND a.value =''
```